# How to improve this routine with lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I have written some code I am not proud of and as a lodash noob I would appreciate some feedback on how to improve this code.

The requirement is to populate an array of timeslots with defaults for certain types of discounts, eg: [image]

For example, there are 6 tables for every discount (top row) for each timeslots going down on the left. At 12:00pm there are 2 tables in the 20% discount column etc. On the right hand side are totals for each timeslot.

I currently have the data in this format:

```
class DiscountTimeTable {
    public restaurantScheduleDiscountId: number;
    public scheduleDiscountId: number;
    public name: string;
    public tables: number;
}

class TablesForTimesAndDiscount {
    public restaurantScheduleDayTimeId: number;
    public timeSlot: string;
    public discounts: Array<DiscountTimeTable>;
}
```

And then I do a foreach loop down the timeslots and then foreach timeslot, another foreach loop across through all discounts. Then, if the discount matches X I check if that time and discount is in another array (discount20Times) and if it is, do something.

The code works, but I am sure it is inefficient - I just don't know what approach to take with Lodash to improve it?

```
public resetDefaults(): void {
        let discount10Times: string[] = ['PT13H30M', 'PT16H30M', 'PT19H30M', 'PT22H30M'];
        let discount20Times: string[] = ['PT12H', 'PT12H30M', 'PT13H', 'PT17H', 'PT17H30M', 'PT18H', 'PT18H30M', 'PT19H', 'PT23H'];

    _.forEach(this.tablesForTimesAndDiscounts, (tablesForTimesAndDiscount: TablesForTimesAndDiscount) => {
        _.forEach(tablesForTimesAndDiscount.discounts, (discount: DiscountTimeTable) => {
            if (discount.scheduleDiscountId === 0) {
                discount.tables = 6;  //regardless of time - all tables
            }
            if (discount.scheduleDiscountId === 10) {
                if (_.find(discount10Times, (time: string) => time == tablesForTimesAndDiscount.timeSlot)) {
                    discount.tables = 2;
                }
            }
            if (discount.scheduleDiscountId === 20) {
                if (_.find(discount20Times, (time: string) => time == tablesForTimesAndDiscount.timeSlot)) {
                    discount.tables = 2;
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can immediately speed up lookups by using an object instead of an array ( the type declarations might be wrong, but you get the idea)

I shortened one of the variable names just to make it easier to read

```
public resetDefaults(): void {
  let discount10Times: Object<string> = {
    PT13H30M: 'PT13H30M', 
    PT16H30M: 'PT16H30M',
    PT19H30M: 'PT22H30M'
  };
  let discount20Times: Object<string> = {
    PT12H:    'PT12H', 
    PT12H30M: 'PT12H30M',
    PT13H:    'PT13H',
    PT17H:    'PT17H',
    PT17H30M: 'PT17H30M',
    PT18H:    'PT18H',
    PT18H30M: 'PT18H30M',
    PT19H:    'PT19H',
    PT23H:    'PT23H'
  };

  _.forEach(this.tablesForTimesAndDiscounts, (timesAndDiscount: TablesForTimesAndDiscount) => {
        _.forEach(timesAndDiscount.discounts, (discount: DiscountTimeTable) => {
          if (discount.scheduleDiscountId === 0) {
            discount.tables = 6;  //regardless of time - all tables
          }
          if (discount.scheduleDiscountId === 10) {
            if (discount10Times[timesAndDiscount.timeSlot]) {
              discount.tables = 2;
            }
          }
          if (discount.scheduleDiscountId === 20) {
            if (discount20Times[timesAndDiscount.timeSlot]) {
              discount.tables = 2;
            }
          }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm yes, that seemed to halve the time on average, thanks. I am still looking for some feedback on my approach in terms of lodash  ORIGINAL
resetDefaults: 20.270ms
resetDefaults: 12.751ms
resetDefaults: 5.770ms
resetDefaults: 3.367ms
resetDefaults: 2.509ms
 resetDefaults: 4.228ms

WITH OBJECT CHANGE
resetDefaults: 14.946ms
resetDefaults: 6.803ms
resetDefaults: 2.814ms
resetDefaults: 1.314ms
resetDefaults: 1.367ms
resetDefaults: 2.641ms

Comment: you code is fine, it's an O(N) operation. the key is proper object caching so you only have to run the calculations when things change

Comment: though i'm still confused by your use of the term tables